# How To Print The Line Where Grep Matched

Tags: bash

I have the below command

`cat url.txt | parallel -j 12 curl -is -k {} 2>&1 | grep -a -n Location: word`

Whats it does is that it issues a curl command with each and every url in the text file and then if the http(s) header has Location: word it prints the match. I would like grep to print the url that caused the match.how can this be done?i tried adding `&& echo $` after the above command but it didnt work.

Thanks

Comment: search pattern *'Location: word'* should be quoted. *-n* is line number of search pattern. if you need line based result for url.txt you must process url.txt line by line

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-v` flag in `parallel` to output each command it is executing and then grab that and your searched string in `grep`.

```
parallel -vj 12 curl -is -k {} 2>&1 < url.txt |
grep -Ean '^(curl |Location: word)'
```

However if you want URL and searched string in one line then you may use `awk` instead of `grep`:

```
parallel -vj 12 curl -is -k {} 2>&1 < url.txt |
awk '/^curl /{url=$NF} /^Location: word/{print url ":", $0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `grep` you can use the `-o` option to print only the match parts of a matching line. Adding the `-P` option allows Perl-compatible regular expressions.

Consider this:

```
echo "The Location: https://google.com and it's valid" | grep -Po ":Location:\s*\K\S+"
```

Yields:

```
 https://google.com
```

The '\s*' (lowercase) is a whitespace repeated zero or more times. The `\K` is a look-behind assertion that allows the preceding pattern to match but not be included in the final match. The `\S+` (uppercase) matches any non-whitespace character on ore more times.

You can add `-a` and `-n` to the `grep` options to accommodate your needs, too.